# How to set tolerance value of ST_Intersects query in TileMill?

Tags: postgis, labeling, intersection, tilemill

I want to place river names in Tilemill. I use "text-dy" to displace label from the center line of a river. But for labeling polygonal rivers, names extracted from lines are used too. So at a small zoom, labels of polygon rivers crawl over river's banks (see attachment_1).

I used `ST_intersects` to exclude from the selection linear rivers being intersected by polygonal ones, and not to displace labels for them:

```
( SELECT way,name,
  FROM planet_osm_line
  WHERE waterway IN ('river','canal') AND name IS NOT NULL
  AND ST_Intersects(way,(
    SELECT ST_Collect(way)
    FROM planet_osm_polygon
    WHERE waterway = 'riverbank' AND way && !bbox!))
) AS riv_center
```

It runs sucessfully, but there are some other problem: line rivers, falling into polygon ones, have short intersection with them and are labelled too (see attachment_2). Maybe one can specify some tolerance for intersection to exclude all line rivers from selection?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Attachment_1]

[image: Attachment_2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that intersection is at least 90% of a river segment's length. And not select it in two layers, but just make it a column: `SELECT way, name, (CASE WHEN ST_Length(ST_Intersection(way, (...))) / ST_Length(way) < 0.3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS linear FROM ...`